# Why will GCC copy word into the return register but not byte?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, x86-64

Is there a logical reason GCC (4.4.7) is not moving the byte from a structure into `%eax` directly, or is it just an optimization oversight?

Consider the following program:

```
struct foo { unsigned char x; };
struct bar { unsigned int x; };

int foo (const struct foo *x, int y) { return x->x * y; }
int bar (const struct bar *x, int y) { return x->x * y; }
```

When compiling with GCC, `foo()` and `bar()` differ more substantially than I expected:

```
foo:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        movzbl  (%rdi), %edx
        movl    %esi, %eax
        imull   %edx, %eax
        ret
        .cfi_endproc

bar:
.LFB1:
        .cfi_startproc
        movl    (%rdi), %eax
        imull   %esi, %eax
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

I expected `foo()` would be just like `bar()`, except using a different move instruction.

I will note that under `clang-500.2.79`, the compiler generates the code I expect for `foo()`, and `foo()` and `bar()` have the same number of instructions (as I had expected for GCC as well, but was wrong).

Comment: Note: I'd expect `foo()` to do a `.x` to `int` (standard promotion) and then `int` * `int` (which it does) whereas I'd expect `bar()` to do a `y` to `unsigned` and then `unsigned` * `unsigned`.  (mull vs imull). Hmmm

Comment: @chux: I think this is one of those cases where signed integer overflow is undefined, so the compiler can choose to do it this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you multiply an uchar x and a uint y in the function foo, the compiler must promote uchar x to int first, which the instruction movzbl just does.

See [the explanation of movz instructions here.](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/references/macvax/op-codes/Instructions/movz.html)

Afterward I recompiled your code with gcc 4.6.1 and -O3 options, I got assembles as follows:

```
foo:
.LFB34:
    .cfi_startproc
    movzbl  (%rdi), %eax
    imull   %esi, %eax
    ret 
    .cfi_endproc

bar:
.LFB35:
    .cfi_startproc
    movl    (%rdi), %eax
    imull   %esi, %eax
    ret 
    .cfi_endproc
```

It doesn't use %edx any more.

Comment: That instruction matches up with the `movl` in `bar`, though - it's not the interesting part of the difference...

Comment: You are saying that the rationale for moving into `%edx` is integer promotion, but moving into `%eax` would have also done the promotion, and allowed the removal of one instruction.

Comment: Afterward I tried to compile these codes with gcc 4.6.3 and -O3 option, I found that the assembles generated from the foo are just like bar, not using %edx.

Comment: @dwelch: Thanks for the advice. When working with small memory systems, storing things as bytes (and even as bits) is desired. I was expecting that using such bytes would not cause a significant impact in number of CPU cycles when doing arithmetic with them, but a 33% increase in instruction size is not insignificant, hence the question.

Comment: @nicky_zs: Thanks, that means `4.4` was just not optimizing well enough. Can you post your findings with `4.6` as part of your answer?

Comment: "the compiler must convert uchar x to type uint first".  Is not the standard promotion to the first size that fits, IWO, convert uchar .x to type _int_?

Comment: @dwelch: I don't think there is any room to debate the architecture (especially in this forum), as I have a closed system with these properties. So, I cannot solve my problem in the way you are suggesting. I can, however, patch the compiler.

Comment: @dwelch: That is utter nonsense. Whether your struct contains 10 byte-size members or 10 int-sized members certainly makes a difference when you have 50 billion instances of the struct.

Comment: @dwelch: That's also false. Accessing bytes on any sane hardware is no slower than accessing full words. In fact it's probably a lot faster because you end up accessing fewer cache lines (since your data fits in fewer cache lines) and having fewer TLB misses and page faults too.

Comment: BTW Abrash is a dinosaur. The stuff he wrote was outdated/wrong when his books were first published in the 90s.

Comment: And structures with uneven sized elements do not lead to misaligned accesses. All structure members have the correct alignment for their types. C does not have misaligned objects. The only way they can come to exist is via undefined behavior (invalid pointer arithmetic and/or casts) or harmful compiler-specific extensions (`#pragma pack` nonsense).

Answer (score 2):

---

The short answer

> Why will GCC copy word into the return register but not byte?

Because you asked it to return a word not a byte.  The compilers did what they were asked based on your code.  You asked for a size promotion in one case and unsigned to signed in both cases.  There was more than one way to do that and clang/llvm and gcc happened to vary.

> Is there a logical reason GCC (4.4.7) is not moving the byte from a structure into %eax directly, or is it just an optimization oversight?

I think based on what we see in the current compilers it was an oversight.  See generated code below.  (-O2 used in each case).

---

Interesting experiments related to this question.

clang

```
0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   0f b6 07                movzbl (%rdi),%eax
   3:   0f af c6                imul   %esi,%eax
   6:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000010 <bar>:
  10:   0f af 37                imul   (%rdi),%esi
  13:   89 f0                   mov    %esi,%eax
  15:   c3                      retq
```

gcc

```
0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   0f b6 07                movzbl (%rdi),%eax
   3:   0f af c6                imul   %esi,%eax
   6:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000010 <bar>:
  10:   8b 07                   mov    (%rdi),%eax
  12:   0f af c6                imul   %esi,%eax
  15:   c3                      retq
```

They both generated proper code.  The tiny difference in the number of bytes of instruction could have really gone either way with these small functions on this instruction set.

Your compiler at the time must not have seen that optimization for some reason.

mips:

```
00000000 <foo>:
   0:   90820000    lbu v0,0(a0)
   4:   00000000    nop
   8:   00450018    mult    v0,a1
   c:   00001012    mflo    v0
  10:   03e00008    jr  ra
  14:   00000000    nop

00000018 <bar>:
  18:   8c820000    lw  v0,0(a0)
  1c:   00000000    nop
  20:   00a20018    mult    a1,v0
  24:   00001012    mflo    v0
  28:   03e00008    jr  ra
  2c:   00000000    nop
```

arm

```
00000000 <foo>:
   0:   e5d00000    ldrb    r0, [r0]
   4:   e0000091    mul r0, r1, r0
   8:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

0000000c <bar>:
   c:   e5900000    ldr r0, [r0]
  10:   e0000091    mul r0, r1, r0
  14:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

No big surprise there like x86 the difference is in the load and how it deals with the other 24 bits then as the code said it promotes the unsigned char or int to signed integer and then multiply and return a signed integer.

Another equally interesting example to complement your question.

```
struct foo { unsigned char x; };
struct bar { unsigned int x; };

char foo (const struct foo *x, char y) { return x->x * y; }
char bar (const struct bar *x, char y) { return x->x * y; }
```

clang

```
0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   8a 07                   mov    (%rdi),%al
   2:   40 f6 e6                mul    %sil
   5:   0f be c0                movsbl %al,%eax
   8:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000010 <bar>:
  10:   0f af 37                imul   (%rdi),%esi
  13:   40 0f be c6             movsbl %sil,%eax
  17:   c3                      retq
```

gcc

```
0000000000000000 <foo>:
   0:   89 f0                   mov    %esi,%eax
   2:   f6 27                   mulb   (%rdi)
   4:   c3                      retq   

0000000000000010 <bar>:
  10:   89 f0                   mov    %esi,%eax
  12:   f6 27                   mulb   (%rdi)
  14:   c3                      retq
```

gcc arm

```
00000000 <foo>:
   0:   e5d00000    ldrb    r0, [r0]
   4:   e0010190    mul r1, r0, r1
   8:   e20100ff    and r0, r1, #255    ; 0xff
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000010 <bar>:
  10:   e5900000    ldr r0, [r0]
  14:   e0010190    mul r1, r0, r1
  18:   e20100ff    and r0, r1, #255    ; 0xff
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

mips

```
00000000 <foo>:
   0:   90820000    lbu v0,0(a0)
   4:   00052e00    sll a1,a1,0x18
   8:   00052e03    sra a1,a1,0x18
   c:   00a20018    mult    a1,v0
  10:   00001012    mflo    v0
  14:   00021600    sll v0,v0,0x18
  18:   03e00008    jr  ra
  1c:   00021603    sra v0,v0,0x18

00000020 <bar>:
  20:   8c820000    lw  v0,0(a0)
  24:   00052e00    sll a1,a1,0x18
  28:   00052e03    sra a1,a1,0x18
  2c:   00a20018    mult    a1,v0
  30:   00001012    mflo    v0
  34:   00021600    sll v0,v0,0x18
  38:   03e00008    jr  ra
  3c:   00021603    sra v0,v0,0x18
```

That code in particular punished mips.

and lastly

```
struct foo { unsigned char x; };
struct bar { unsigned int x; };

unsigned char foo (const struct foo *x, unsigned char y) { return x->x * y; }
unsigned char bar (const struct bar *x, unsigned char y) { return x->x * y; }
```

gcc and clang for x86 produce the same code as above with the non-specified chars, but

arm

```
00000000 <foo>:
   0:   e5d00000    ldrb    r0, [r0]
   4:   e0010190    mul r1, r0, r1
   8:   e20100ff    and r0, r1, #255    ; 0xff
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000010 <bar>:
  10:   e5900000    ldr r0, [r0]
  14:   e0010190    mul r1, r0, r1
  18:   e20100ff    and r0, r1, #255    ; 0xff
  1c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

mips

```
00000000 <foo>:
   0:   90820000    lbu v0,0(a0)
   4:   30a500ff    andi    a1,a1,0xff
   8:   00a20018    mult    a1,v0
   c:   00001012    mflo    v0
  10:   03e00008    jr  ra
  14:   304200ff    andi    v0,v0,0xff

00000018 <bar>:
  18:   8c820000    lw  v0,0(a0)
  1c:   30a500ff    andi    a1,a1,0xff
  20:   00a20018    mult    a1,v0
  24:   00001012    mflo    v0
  28:   03e00008    jr  ra
  2c:   304200ff    andi    v0,v0,0xff
```

Masking needed because of a combination of calling convention and instruction set.  A punishment on both of these instruction sets...You will see this often when using variables whose size do not match the register size for instruction sets like these. x86 has a much wider array of instruction choices, the costs for x86 is the power (watts) that that additional logic costs.

For grins, even if you go way way back, the register sized choice is slightly cheaper.

```
00000000 <_foo>:
   0:   1166            mov r5, -(sp)
   2:   1185            mov sp, r5
   4:   9f40 0004       movb    *4(r5), r0
   8:   45c0 ff00       bic $-400, r0
   c:   1001            mov r0, r1
   e:   7075 0006       mul 6(r5), r1
  12:   1040            mov r1, r0
  14:   1585            mov (sp)+, r5
  16:   0087            rts pc

00000018 <_bar>:
  18:   1166            mov r5, -(sp)
  1a:   1185            mov sp, r5
  1c:   1d41 0006       mov 6(r5), r1
  20:   707d 0004       mul *4(r5), r1
  24:   1040            mov r1, r0
  26:   1585            mov (sp)+, r5
  28:   0087            rts pc
```

compiler versions

```
gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

clang --version
clang version 3.4 (branches/release_34 201060)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix

arm-none-eabi-gcc --version
arm-none-eabi-gcc (GCC) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

mips-elf-gcc --version
mips-elf-gcc (GCC) 4.8.2
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And that last instruction set is an exercise for the reader, there is a bit of a clue in the disassembly...

Comment: The point being that compilers are not perfect, even good compilers dont always choose the instruction you would have chosen and not pointed out but in my experience studying compiler output over time a compiler like gcc or clang sometimes gets better, sometimes worse.  Sometimes chooses really nice solutions sometimes gets tripped up really bad.  Often if you choose to take or waste the time depending on how you feel about it, certainly in C, you can manipulate the compiler into doing certain things.

Comment: In this case the jumping in size in the one case and then unsigned and signed requires the compiler to do these conversions and opens the door for the compiler wisely or not to add more instructions.  You can do a lot of tuning if you are isolating one target, but you can also do some general tuning for any target (dont do so many conversions in the code).